# Odd Behavior When Using Generic Delegate Command In Prism / Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I am attempting to use the `DelegateCommand<T>` type from the Prism assembly.

Suppose I have the following in my view model:

```
public DelegateCommand<int> TestCommand
{
    get;

    set;
}

public void TestCommandExecute(int parameter)
{
    return;
}
```

In the constructor of the view model I initialize the `TestCommand` property with the following:

```
TestCommand = new DelegateCommand<int>(TestCommandExecute);
```

If I do this, the application seems to *crash* and a *blank* screen is displayed. I also observed that the OnNavigatedTo method is never called in this case.

I have observed that if I change the type of `TestCommand` from `DelegateCommand<int>` to `DelegateCommand` (and then adjust the signature of the `TestCommandExecute` method accordingly, the application does not *crash* and behaves as expected.

I do not see any errors being written to the output window so I am at a complete loss.

Comment: What's your parameter? Can you show the xaml that calls the command? If you pass a `string` when the command expects an `int` I wouldn't be too surprised of an exception...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely culprit here is that a null is being passed in as the Command Parameter. You might try making the command use a nullable int like so:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public FooViewModel()
    {
        // Prevent execution of null int
        MyCommand = new DelegateCommand<int?>(OnMyCommandExecuted, p => p != null);
    }
}
```

As for the exception this is likely due to the fact that you aren't checking the NavigationResult when you navigated to the new View. You can do this easily like shown below:

```
var result = await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("Foo");

if(!result.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Exception);
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```

Comment: Somehow, I managed to catch an exception related to this (not sure how I was missing it before). The text of the exception read, "T for DelegateCommand<T> is not an object nor Nullable." I switched the definition of the command from `DelegateCommand<int>` to `DelegateCommand<int?>` and the issue went away. Since that is more or less what you responded with in the first part of your answer, I will mark it as the accepted solution.